# heutige Kommasetzung nach "d. h." im Vergleich zu 1930

Tags: comma

In dem Artikel "Die Vollständigkeit der Axiome des logischen Funktionenkalküls" aus dem Jahre 1930 hat Kurt Gödel geschrieben:

> Bei einem solchen Vorgehen erhebt sich natürlich sofort die Frage, ob das an die Spitze gestellte System von Axiomen und Schlußprinzipien vollständig ist, d. h. wirklich dazu ausreicht, jeden logisch-mathematischen Satz zu deduzieren, oder ob vielleicht [...]

Mich interessiert, ob nach heutiger Rechtschreibung nach dem "d. h." ein Komma gesetzt werden müsste.
Also: Müsste es nach heutiger Rechtschreibung folgendermaßen geschrieben werden?

> Bei einem solchen Vorgehen erhebt sich natürlich sofort die Frage, ob das an die Spitze gestellte System von Axiomen und Schlußprinzipien vollständig ist, d. h.**,** wirklich dazu ausreicht, jeden logisch-mathematischen Satz zu deduzieren, oder ob vielleicht [...]

Comment: Ja, das kannst du machen.

Comment: Nach heutiger Rechtschreibung müsste man allerdings _Schlussprinzipien_ statt _Schlußprinzipien_ schreiben.

Comment: @Loong: Danke für die Bemerkung.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Nach "d. h." oder "das heißt" steht nur dann ein Komma,
wenn ein *vollständiger Satz* (Hauptsatz oder Nebensatz) folgt.
Das ist hier nicht der Fall; bei "wirklich dazu ausreicht"
fehlt insbesondere ein Subjekt.

Würde man den Satz wie folgt ändern,

> ... die Frage, ob das an die Spitze gestellte System von Axiomen und Schlußprinzipien vollständig ist, d. h., *ob es* wirklich dazu ausreicht, ...

dann würde hingegen ein Komma gesetzt, denn "*ob es* wirklich dazu ausreicht,
..." ist ein vollständiger Nebensatz.

Comment: Ich möchte mich bei Ihnen (darf ich Sie duzen, Herr Doktor?) bedanken. Sieht so aus, als wären Sie der Experte für die Rechtschreibung mathematischer Sätze :-)

Comment: @ririirir Du darfst mich duzen, so wie jeden anderen hier auch.

Comment: @ririirir: Das ist ein mathematischer Satz: »A⊆B⟺∀x(x∈A→x∈B)«. Das hingegen ist ein deutscher Satz: »Es erhebt sich die Frage, ob das System vollständig ist, d. h. wirklich dazu ausreicht, jeden logisch-mathematischen Satz zu deduzieren.« Rechtschreibung wiederum ist die Lehre, die sich damit beschäftigt, wie Wörter zu schreiben sind. Wörter sind aber keine Sätze (weder mathematische noch deutsche). Zur Beurteilung der Wohlgeformtheit von Sätzen bedient man sich eines Fachs, das *Grammatik* heißt (sowohl in deutschen als auch in mathematischen Sätzen).